# WKWebView : how to open another WKWebView in objc

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

I have a wkwebview on hybrid App.

When loaded first page, I'd like to open another wkwebview page.

So, I made blow code, but, it doesn't work.

How to open new one?

```
== PermissionViewController.h ==

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface PermissionViewController : UIViewController < WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate >


@property(nonatomic) WKWebView *webView2;

+ (id) sharedManager;
- (void) openWKWebView;

@end


== PermissionViewController.m ==

#import "PermissionViewController.h"


@implementation PermissionViewController

+(id) sharedManager{
    static PermissionViewController *permissionView = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{permissionView = [[self alloc] init];});
    
    return permissionView;
}

...
...
...

-(void)openWKWebView{
    
    NSLog(@"PermissionViewController callWKWebView start");
    
    WKWebView *mainview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [mainview setUIDelegate:self];
    [mainview setNavigationDelegate:self];
    
    [self.view addSubview:mainview];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mydomain/login/agree.jsp"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [mainview loadRequest:request];
    
    NSLog(@"PermissionViewController callWKWebView end");
}


== console.log ==
```

16:24:58    MobileE onAppForeground start

16:24:58    MobileE call PermissionView start

16:24:58    MobileE PermissionViewController callWKWebView start

16:24:58    MobileE PermissionViewController loadView start

16:24:58    MobileE PermissionViewController viewDidLoad start

16:24:58    MobileE PermissionViewController loadView start

16:24:58    MobileE PermissionViewController viewDidLoad start

16:24:58    MobileE PermissionViewController callWKWebView end

16:24:58    MobileE onAppForeground end

Comment: If you format the code message then the line breaks will work. You can also use markdown to create titles by using == title == instead of —-

Comment: Not sure of the logic, e.g. you never use ```webView2``` but I think you need to move some of it to the ```WKNavigationDelegate``` specifically to the ```decisionHandler``` in ```- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler```